# Lie Brackets are independent of coordinate charts

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

I have been trying to do the computations to prove that the Lie brackets $[X,Y]$ are independent of coordinate chart for a while now, but I can´t seem to put the things together.

Let $X|_U = X^i\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}$ and $Y|_U = Y^i\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}$ be vector fields via a coordinate chart $(U,\phi =(x^1,\dots,x^n))$ and $X|_V = \tilde X^i\frac{\partial }{\partial y^i}$ and $Y|_V = \tilde Y^i\frac{\partial }{\partial y^i}$ vector fields in coordinate chart $(V,\psi=(y^1,\dots,y^n))$ .

I would like to prove the following identity.

$$[X,Y]|_U = \sum_{i,j} \left(X^i \frac{\partial Y^j}{\partial x^i} - Y^i\frac{\partial X^j}{\partial x^i}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} = \sum_{i,j} \left( \tilde X^i \frac{\partial \tilde Y^j}{\partial y^i} - \tilde Y^i\frac{\partial \tilde X^j}{\partial y^i}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i} = [X,Y]|_V $$

I am aware that the identity $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} = \sum_{i} \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$ is usefull.

I am aware as well that there are some questions in MSE that are pointing to this topic, but no one is quite elucidative, my difficulty falls in doing the right manipulations.

Comment: The Lie bracket has a minus sign not a plus. Also, the identity you quote is wrong it should be $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$. Now figure out how the components $X^i$ and $\tilde{X}^i$ are related and put all of this together.

Comment: thanks for the comments on the typos